# Google Cloud : Error creating AlertPolicy: googleapi: Error 403

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, bitbucket, google-cloud-monitoring, gcp-alerts

We are triggering a bitbucket pipeline which provisions resources via terraform.

Service account with a role(comprising of appropriate permissions) is passed to job to make sure job succeeds.

While provisioning a google alert we saw below error

```
╷
│ Error: Error creating AlertPolicy: googleapi: Error 403: The caller does not have permission
│ 
│   with module.abc.google_monitoring_alert_policy.abc_error,
```

Role which is attached to service account has several permissions including related to alerting

```
monitoring.alertPolicies.create
monitoring.alertPolicies.delete
monitoring.alertPolicies.get
monitoring.alertPolicies.update
```

So it has permission to create alert policy but it is failing.

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 IAM roles and anyone of those three should be in place to create alerting policy in GCP

### Monitoring Editor

Grants read-write access to Monitoring in the Google Cloud console and API,
and grants read-write access to a metrics scope when using the Google Cloud console. Write access to a metrics scope grants permission to add (or remove) monitored Google Cloud projects to that metrics scope.

Predefined role : `roles/monitoring.editor`

### Monitoring Admin

Grants full access to Monitoring in the Google Cloud console and API,
and grants read-write access to a metrics scope. Write access to a metrics scope grants permission to add (or remove) monitored Google Cloud projects to that metrics scope.

Predefined role : `roles/monitoring.admin`

### Project Owner

The Monitoring permissions are the same as those in roles/monitoring.admin.

Predefined role : `roles/owner`

### Alert Policy Editor

This role ID grants the minimal permissions that are needed to create an alerting policy.
It has

```
monitoring.alertPolicies.create
monitoring.alertPolicies.delete
monitoring.alertPolicies.get
monitoring.alertPolicies.list
monitoring.alertPolicies.update
```

Predefined role : `roles/monitoring.alertPolicyEditor`

##### Use either predefined role `roles/monitoring.alertPolicyEditor` or add `monitoring.alertPolicies.list` in order to create a alert policy.

##### Note :

Sometimes an alerting policy requires some extra permissions related to cloud logging and notification channels so you might need to provide `roles/monitoring.editor` role to create alerting policy.

### References :

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts#cc-perms
https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts#api-perms

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem and resolved it by updating the permissions as outlined in this document:

**Permissions Required for Log-Based Alerts:** [Google Cloud Logging Access Control - Log-Based Alert Permissions](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/access-control#lba-permissions)

It turned out that the `roles/logging.configWriter` role was not assigned to my service account, and adding it resolved the issue.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, adding `roles/logging.configWriter` role to the SA fixed my terraform code as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. I used the workaround described [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/11603) (assing project editor role) but can hardly imagine that it is intended to have all these permissions assigned to create an alert policy.

Update: I got some good advise on [Github](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/14598) to check for the conditions block in the alert and to check which privileges are required for those. For me it ended up being the logging privileges.